# Get 'X' number of records on DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying know if exist something similar to `TOP` in `SQL` on `DynamoDB`
I'm reading the documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html 
But I didn't find something similar.
Someones knows a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Limit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#ScanQueryLimit) in Scan/Query is what you were looking for

Answer (score 1):

Both [ScanRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/ScanRequest.html) and [QueryRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/QueryRequest.html) have a `withLimit` function for [limiting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#ScanQueryLimit) the maximum number of items to evaluate for a request.

From the documentation:

> The maximum number of items to evaluate (not necessarily the number of
>   matching items). If DynamoDB processes the number of items up to the
>   limit while processing the results, it stops the operation and returns
>   the matching values up to that point, and a key in LastEvaluatedKey to
>   apply in a subsequent operation, so that you can pick up where you
>   left off. Also, if the processed data set size exceeds 1 MB before
>   DynamoDB reaches this limit, it stops the operation and returns the
>   matching values up to the limit, and a key in LastEvaluatedKey to
>   apply in a subsequent operation to continue the operation. For more
>   information, see Query and Scan in the Amazon DynamoDB Developer
>   Guide.